# Data.Text.Lazy.Internal.Text to Data.Text.Text

Tags: haskell

How can I convert the internal value to a `Data.Text.Text`?

```
import qualified Data.Text as T
import qualified Data.Text.Lazy.IO as X

main = do
    name <- X.readFile "someFile"
```

How can I convert the value in `name` to `T.Text`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a function explicitly for that, [`Data.Text.Lazy.toStrict`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/text/0.11.2.3/doc/html/Data-Text-Lazy.html#v%3atoStrict).

I suppose you're actually doing something else in between that requires reading as a lazy `Text`, otherwise, you should [read as a strict `Text`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/text/0.11.2.3/doc/html/Data-Text-IO.html#v%3areadFile) directly of course.

Comment: Thank you. Your answer led me on the right path. I was in fact mixing and matching lazy vs. strict in my code.